# Password encryption algorithm throws exception when converted to JS from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

Below is a password hashing algorithm I *must* use for the control panel I'm building. The original function is in PHP but I'm rewriting it for use with Node.js in JavaScript.

Everything seems to go fine, but then I do a call to `fMod` and get a crash:

```
RangeError: toFixed() digits argument must be between 0 and 20
```

The `fmod` function seems to be working correctly though with other values. I have marked the line in `fMod` that throws the exception.

The correct hash for the password *should* be:

```
0x31c7296631df873d0891b7b77ae0c6c6
```

Code:

```
// JavaScript Version
var pass = "Cake99";

console.log(pCrypt2(pass));

function pCrypt2(plain) {

    var array_mul = [213119, 213247, 213203, 213821];
    var array_add = [2529077, 2529089, 2529589, 2529997];
    var dst = Array.apply(null, new Array(16)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf,0);
    var key = Array.apply(null, new Array(16)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf,0);

    for (var i = 0; i < plain.length; i++ ) {
        dst[i] = key[i] = ord(plain.substr(i, 1));
    }

    var val = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++ ) {
        val[i] = fmod((key[i * 4 + 0] + key[i * 4 + 1] * 0x100 + key[i * 4 + 2] * 0x10000 + key[i * 4 + 3] * 0x1000000) * array_mul[i] + array_add[i], 4294967296 );
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++ ) {
        key[i * 4 + 0] = val[i] & 0xff;
        key[i * 4 + 1] = val[i] / 0x100 & 0xff;
        key[i * 4 + 2] = val[i] / 0x10000 & 0xff;
        key[i * 4 + 3] = val[i] / 0x1000000 & 0xff;
    }

    dst[0] =  dst[0] ^ key[0];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 15; i++ ) {
        dst[i] = dst[i] ^ dst[i - 1] ^ key[i];
    }

    for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++ ) {
        if (dst [i] == 0 ) {
            dst [i] = 0x66;
        }
    }

    var encrypted = "0x";
    for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++ ) {
        if (dst [i] < 16 ) {
            encrypted = encrypted + "0";
        }
        encrypted = encrypted + dst[i].toString(16);

    }
    return (encrypted);
}

function ord(string) {
    //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/ord/
    // original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
    // improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
    //    input by: incidence
    var str = string + '',
        code = str.charCodeAt(0);
    if (0xD800 <= code && code <= 0xDBFF) { // High surrogate (could change last hex to 0xDB7F to treat high private surrogates as single characters)
        var hi = code;
        if (str.length === 1) {
            return code; // This is just a high surrogate with no following low surrogate, so we return its value;
            // we could also throw an error as it is not a complete character, but someone may want to know
        }
        var low = str.charCodeAt(1);
        return ((hi - 0xD800) * 0x400) + (low - 0xDC00) + 0x10000;
    }
    if (0xDC00 <= code && code <= 0xDFFF) { // Low surrogate
        return code; // This is just a low surrogate with no preceding high surrogate, so we return its value;
        // we could also throw an error as it is not a complete character, but someone may want to know
    }
    return code;
}

function fmod(x, y) {
    //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/fmod/
    // original by: Onno Marsman
    //    input by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
    // bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    //   example 1: fmod(5.7, 1.3);
    //   returns 1: 0.5

    var tmp, tmp2, p = 0,
        pY = 0,
        l = 0.0,
        l2 = 0.0;

    tmp = x.toExponential()
        .match(/^.\.?(.*)e(.+)$/);
    p = parseInt(tmp[2], 10) - (tmp[1] + '')
        .length;
    tmp = y.toExponential()
        .match(/^.\.?(.*)e(.+)$/);
    pY = parseInt(tmp[2], 10) - (tmp[1] + '')
        .length;

    if (pY > p) {
        p = pY;
    }

    tmp2 = (x % y);

    if (p < -100 || p > 20) {
        // toFixed will give an out of bound error so we fix it like this:
        l = Math.round(Math.log(tmp2) / Math.log(10));
        l2 = Math.pow(10, l);

        return (tmp2 / l2)
            .toFixed(l - p) * l2;
    } else {
        return parseFloat(tmp2.toFixed(-p)); <<< ---- FAILS HERE ---------
    }
}
```

// PHP Original --------------------------------

```
function encrypt( $plain )
{
  $array_mul = array ( 0 => 213119, 1 => 213247, 2 => 213203, 3 => 213821 );
  $array_add = array ( 0 => 2529077, 1 => 2529089, 2 => 2529589, 3 => 2529997 );
  $dst = $key = array ( 0 => 0, 1 => 0, 2 => 0, 3 => 0, 4 => 0, 5 => 0, 6 => 0, 7 => 0, 8 => 0, 9 => 0, 10 => 0, 11 => 0, 12 => 0, 13 => 0, 14 => 0, 15 => 0 );

  for ( $i = 0; $i < strlen ( $plain ); $i++ ) {
    $dst [ $i ] = $key [ $i ] = ord ( substr ( $plain, $i, 1 ) );
  }

  for ( $i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++ ) {
    $val [ $i ] = fmod ( ( $key [ $i * 4 + 0 ] + $key [ $i * 4 + 1 ] * 0x100 + $key [ $i * 4 + 2 ] * 0x10000 + $key [ $i * 4 + 3 ] * 0x1000000 ) * $array_mul [ $i ] + $array_add [ $i ], 4294967296 );
  }

  for ( $i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++ ) {
    $key [ $i * 4 + 0 ] = $val [ $i ] & 0xff;
    $key [ $i * 4 + 1 ] = $val [ $i ] / 0x100 & 0xff;
    $key [ $i * 4 + 2 ] = $val [ $i ] / 0x10000 & 0xff;
    $key [ $i * 4 + 3 ] = $val [ $i ] / 0x1000000 & 0xff;
  }

  $dst [ 0 ] = $dst [ 0 ] ^ $key [ 0 ];
  for ( $i = 1; $i <= 15; $i++ ) {
    $dst [ $i ] = $dst [ $i ] ^ $dst [ $i - 1 ] ^ $key [ $i ];
  }

  for ( $i = 0; $i <= 15; $i++ ) {
    if ( $dst [ $i ] == 0 ) {
      $dst [ $i ] = 0x66;
    }
  }

  $encrypted = "0x";
  for ( $i = 0; $i <= 15; $i++ ) {
    if ( $dst [ $i ] < 16 ) {
      $encrypted .= "0";
    }
    $encrypted .= dechex($dst[$i]);
  }
  return ( $encrypted );
}
```

Comment: Looks like the FMOD function doesn't like the number 362629667592050 which is the result of the call to it. It seems to only work with values which are not made up of many of the same number. EX 1111, 2222, 3333 etc.

Comment: Could you give me some input about the answer below? I think there are a couple of ways we can fix this.

Comment: Your answer is phenomenal. Thank you so much! Bounty is yours in 56 mins (cannot award yet for some reason). Your solution was extremely well written and taught me a few things about JS i didn't know. You also provided a way to not "just make it work" but to keep the original FMOD function intact and working as it should.

Comment: Yes but I'm afraid you need to change your pCrypt2 function. If you can go a bit deeper into it, I'm sure you can find other alternatives (such as trying to make js allow more digits)

Comment: I would also suggest pointing this out to the developer of the fmod js implementation

Answer (score 5):

You are passing `-p` to as the number of digits to `parseFloat()` in line 111, in this part of the code:

```
....
if (p < -100 || p > 20) {
    // toFixed will give an out of bound error so we fix it like this:
    l = Math.round(Math.log(tmp2) / Math.log(10));
    l2 = Math.pow(10, l);

    return (tmp2 / l2)
        .toFixed(l - p) * l2;
} else {
    return parseFloat(tmp2.toFixed(-p)); 
}
```

At the moment of evaluation, `-p` equals `-1`.

For purposes of demonstration, if we change the last three lines to

```
...
} else {

    for(var i=0; i<=20;i++) {
        console.log(parseFloat(tmp2.toFixed(i)));
    }
    //return parseFloat(tmp2.toFixed(-p)); 
}
```

We get

```
2529997
2529997
2529997
...
2529997
2529997
2529997
```

This is because in line 101, you are getting the modulo of two integers.

```
tmp2 = (x % y);
```

*The modulo of two integers is always an integer in JavaScript*.

And so, **using any value for the number of digits in parseFloat() in line 112 returns the same value**:

```
...
} else {
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*20);
    return parseFloat(tmp2.toFixed(i)); 
}
```

And running the script:

```
alain@vaio ~/dev/test % node script.js
0x31c7296631df873d0891b7b77ae0c6c6
alain@vaio ~/dev/test % node script.js
0x31c7296631df873d0891b7b77ae0c6c6
alain@vaio ~/dev/test % node script.js
0x31c7296631df873d0891b7b77ae0c6c6
alain@vaio ~/dev/test % node script.js
0x31c7296631df873d0891b7b77ae0c6c6
alain@vaio ~/dev/test % node script.js
0x31c7296631df873d0891b7b77ae0c6c6
alain@vaio ~/dev/test % node script.js
0x31c7296631df873d0891b7b77ae0c6c6
```

So yes, lose the minus sign, or delete p entirely if you will only be dealing with integers.

#### There are another couple of ways you can fix this.

Note that `Number.prototype.toFixed()` will throw a RangeError when `p > 0`. Because of the way p is calculated, this occurs when there's rounding, or when there are leading zeros:

```
> x = 12345; tmp = x.toExponential().match(/^.\.?(.*)e(.+)$/); p = parseInt(tmp[2], 10) - (tmp[1] + '').length;
0

> x = 1234567890123456789; tmp = x.toExponential().match(/^.\.?(.*)e(.+)$/); p = parseInt(tmp[2], 10) - (tmp[1] + '').length;
2

> x = 101000; tmp = x.toExponential().match(/^.\.?(.*)e(.+)$/); p = parseInt(tmp[2], 10) - (tmp[1] + '').length;
3
```

You are currently calling fmod with x: 3626296650629732529077 and y: 4294967296, which results in p = 1.

You could either modify the fmod function to reject negative values:

```
if (p < -100 || p > 20) {
    // toFixed will give an out of bound error so we fix it like this:
    l = Math.round(Math.log(tmp2) / Math.log(10));
    l2 = Math.pow(10, l);

    return (tmp2 / l2)
        .toFixed(l - p) * l2;
} else if ( p > 0 ) {
    return parseFloat(tmp2.toFixed(p)); 
} else {
    return parseFloat(tmp2.toFixed(-p)); 
}
```

Our modify your `pCrypt2` function to use a smaller x.

See [Number.prototype.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) for more details on JavaScript rounding.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
return parseFloat(tmp2.toFixed(-p));
```

with:

```
return parseFloat(tmp2.toFixed(p));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rd13/7UHdw/